# Angular nested children routing not routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to create some nested children routing.

The first parent route is to prevent the user from accessing anything on the app if they have not logged in. That is what the `AuthGuardService` is for.

Then i have an admin component that can only be accessed if the user is an admin. It has children that also need to be protected by the `AdminGuardService`.

All these routes seem to be working except the `users` route. When i go to `admin/users` nothing happens. It does not navigate and does not give me an error. It just sits on the page you are located. I would expect it to run through the `adminguard` and then route to the `users` page.

When i take the `admin/users` route and move it outside the children block it works. The location is indicated by my comment in the code below.

What am i doing wrong? How do i get this to work?

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: BaseComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        children: [
            {path: "", redirectTo: "/boards", pathMatch: "full"},
            {path: "boards", component: BoardsComponent},
            {
                path: "admin",
                component: AdminComponent,
                canActivate: [AdminGuardService],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "",
                        children: [
                            {path: "users", component: AdminUsersComponent}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            // {path: "admin/users", component: AdminUsersComponent}
        ]
    },
    {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginComponent
    }
];
```

---

This also does not work.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "admin",
        component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
            { path: "users", component: AdminUsersComponent },
        ]
    }
]
```

---

This Works, but is not what i am wanting...

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: BaseComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        children: [
            {path: "", redirectTo: "/boards", pathMatch: "full"},
            {path: "boards", component: BoardsComponent},
            {
                path: "admin",
                component: AdminComponent,
                canActivate: [AdminGuardService]
            },
            {
                path: "admin/users",
                component: AdminUsersComponent,
                canActivate: [AdminGuardService]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginComponent
    }
];
```

Comment: whats the point of the second children inside the admin?, if you take out the second children and just have like path: 'users', component: AdminUsersComponent, does it work ?

Comment: @dAxx_ Just doing what the documentation says. Link is given below. However, taking it out does not result in this working. It still does the same thing. https://angular.io/guide/router#component-less-route-grouping-routes-without-a-component

Comment: Im sorry for doing it in comments but im not sure its the answer, Try to replace the entire admin block with this: { path: "admin", component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AdminGuardService], children: [ { path: "", redirectTo: 'users'}, {path: "users", component: AdminUsersComponent}} ] },

Comment: @dAxx_ Just put it as an answer. If it works, it works. No need to try and shove all this into the comments.

Comment: @dAxx_ That does not work.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem within your AdminGuard? Just to be clear, when you call canActivate its only check the specific route, in your case: /admin, and admin/users would not call the Guard, if you would like to do so, you have to change it to canActivateChild so it will perform the validation on the child routes too, maybe you can add the guard so I can see maybe something broken there.

Comment: @dAxx_ It is calling my `adminguard` on the `admin/users` route. And it is working correctly. It is hitting my breakpoints in the guard and working correctly. Just doesn't route to the `admin/users` page.

Comment: @dAxx_ Adding the `canActivateChild` did not help. It just called both `canActivate` and `canActivateChild` when trying to route to `admin/users`.

Comment: You said that if you take it out of admin child it works, so I assumed that something is not working correctly in the guard, since its the only thing that differentiate the two situations. I cannot help much without see the code which handle the requests. also, maybe try to add a wildcard route to handle 404 errors and check if it redirect when you hit the route or it is still not navigate to anywhere.

Comment: Wildcard route did nothing. Still does no routing. Just stays where you are and passes the guard. No network errors.

Comment: @dAxx_ Added a section of code to the question that shows it working, but i want to use children to do this.

Comment: @dAxx_ Updated with another example that does not work, that i would expect to work.

Comment: I have component: AdminComponent in the parent. If i take that out of the parent for the admin children, everything works fine. Thanks to @dAxx_ for helping find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really weird behavior, so I've tried to recreate the problem and tried this structure and it did work. This structure should work, unless it is something broken inside your guards:

```
   {
    path: "admin",
    canActivate: [AdminGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: AdminComponent
      },
      {
        path: "users",
        component: AdminUsersComponent
      }
    ]
  },
```

In my attempt, there was no Guard and the structure was:

> /
>  /admin 
>  /admin/test

Comment: I took the guards completely out and it is still not working.

Comment: Did you try this structure? its different from all the others in this post

Comment: I found the problem by looking at your answer. I have `component: AdminComponent` in the parent. If i take that out of the parent for the admin children, everything works fine.

Comment: Add an edit to your answer stating that was the problem and i will accept your answer. Thank you for your assistance. What a stupid issue... lol

Comment: @prolink007, yes that is why I post the answer now, Its that what took my attention. Please edit my answer with the right version of your code, since there are so many attempts in your question I dont know exactly what you talk about right now, and I will approve your edit so you can mark as answer

Comment: @prolink007 You mean that you dont want AdminComponent at all? or just add an empty path with AdminComponent and another one with users?Cause this is exactly as my answer state.